# How to use Laravel DB to fetch data from dynamically created tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have been creating an application in Laravel 5.3 and because of the nature of the application, I needed to create a table specific to each user that registers. To do so I have used the homeController (user is redirected to it after a successful registration) and this code is used in  it :

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$user_name = Auth::user()->name;
$table_name = $user_name . '_' . $user_id;

if (Schema::hasTable($table_name))
{   
    $specs = DB::table($table_name)->select('select * from ' . $table_name);
    return view('home')->with('rvalue', $specs);
}else{      
    Schema::connection('mysql')->create($table_name, function ($table){
        $value = 0;
        $table->string('address')->default($value);
        $table->string('phone')->default($value);
        $table->string('name')->default($value);
    });
}
```

As of the code in home.blade.php I've added :

```
foreach ($rvalue as $value)
{
    var_dump($value);
}
```

My problem is that although the table and the columns in it are created and present in the database, I still don't know how to retrieve the default value that is assigned to the columns at the time of their creation and send and display them in the view. 
I would be very thankful of you if you could tell me how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Your query to database must be like this:

```
DB::table($table_name)->select('*')->get();
```

Select method used to specified selected fields, not for query it self.

Read official documentation for more useful methods: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries

Comment: And buy the way, you may not specified `select('*')` because it is default value for query.

Comment: I tried to use `$langs = DB::table($table_name)->get();` in the controller and a `foreach loop` in the view to display the data. Nothing is shown. in `foreach` I've put `echo $value->specs;`. I don't understand anything. Please help me.